# Understanding convolutional filters

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.00712), In which they mentioned about

> Each set of shared weights is called a kernel,
>   or a *convolution kernel*. Thus, a convolutional layer with *n*
>   kernels learns to detect *n* local features whose strength across
>   the input images is visible in the resulting *n* feature maps.

I don't understand the meaning of 'visible' in this context.

Comment: The last sentence of your question makes no grammatical sense, can you rewrite and clarify your actual question?

Comment: I don't think this sentence makes much sense, so don't worry about it too much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, each convolution kernel is responsible for a specific kind of pattern, e.g. edges of different direction, corners, blobs of different colors and etc. For example, if a convolution kernel is responsible for horizontal edges, then the resulting feature map will have evident activation in corresponding location. The strength of each kernel is visible in the resulting feature map because the patterns they are responsible for will have evident activations.

Here is a demo in a browser which you can play with -> https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/mnist.html